# Parameter with that position [1] did not exist after moving the native query into a NamedNativeQuery?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Why do I get the following error when I move a JPA native query no longer work when I move it into a named one?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

Not working query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
                name = Test.TEST,
                query = "SELECT * FROM test_table where id = ?",

Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(Test.TEST);
q.setParameter(1, 362L);
List<Object> result = q.getResultList();
```

This works:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_table where id = ?");
q.setParameter(1, 362L);
List<Object> result = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I think the correct syntax for NativeQueryAnnotations is "SELECT * FROM test_table where id = ?1"
But I'am not sure though...

Comment: I did try that as well. It does work only with the not named one. Same as using a named parameter like :id. While it is unsupported with JPA it does work because I sue hibernate. I must have missed something with else with the NamedNativeQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should be calling:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Test.TEST);
```

and not

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(Test.TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to move you are native query in to named one.
  -Then you will have to do something like below.
- Considering you are example i have one class by name Test and i have one native query which i would like to convert it into a named one let name it as "testQuery"
- so you are TestRepository looks like below which contains one method by same name of named query and further we can call that by its name so it will point your namedQuery(name-testQuery).
- Test testQuery(@param("id")int id)
- And below is your namednative query and you can place it above the entity
- @NamedNativeQuery(
              name = Test.testQuery,
              query = "SELECT * FROM test_table where id = :id")

-Hop it will be helpful.